# can someone help me by telling me the complexity of the following algorithem?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand whether the following solution is of `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)` time complexity.

```
for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++)
     ....
     for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
          ....
          for (int k=i+1; k<array.length-1; k++)
               ...
```

first loop running for all of the array with the index `i`.
second loop running from 0 to the index `i`.
third loop running from the index `i` to the end of the array.

Comment: So, what do you think? :)

Comment: Hint: it's visiting each cell once.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: its not homework, its a solution that i tried in an exam and i really hope its n^2 :)

Comment: Hey @Tdebby there is a good answer posted below, don't forget to read it, understand it and *accept* it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code's complexity can be equivalenty evaluated from the following expression :

[image]

where `n=array.length`.

If you compute this big sum, you will find out that it results to `(1/6)*n*(n^2-13)` = `(1/6)*n^3 - (13/6)*n`, which gives a complexity of `O(n^3)`.